# React can't figure out how to change a text through buttons onClick events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, Nodejs and JavaScript so bear with me.
I'm doing some practice with `onClick` events to change text by clicking some buttons, I have an `input type="checkbox"` to make the text bold when checked and vise versa, 2 **buttons** to increase and decrease the text size by 1+ or 1- and a span that shows the current text size (16 is my default), and finally a span with the `id="textSpan"` that have the text meant to be modified. I also want this buttons, the checkbox and the span with the `id="fontSizeSpan"` that shows the current font size to be hidden by default and when you click the text it appears on its left.

This is the code so far:

```
class FontChooser extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {hidden: true};
this.checkInput = React.createRef();
this.hide = React.createRef();
}

toggle(){
    this.setState({hidden: !this.state.hidden});
    this.hide.current
}
makeBold(){
    this.setState({bold: !this.state.bold});
    this.checkInput.current
}
changeSize(){
    this.setState({size: !this.props.size})
    for(var i = this.props.size; i <= this.props.max; i++);
}

render() {
    
return(
       <div>

        <input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" ref={this.hide} hidden={false} onClick={this.makeBold.bind(this)}/>
        <button id="decreaseButton" ref={this.hide} hidden={false}>-</button>
        <span id="fontSizeSpan" ref={this.hide} hidden={false}>{this.props.size}</span>
        <button id="increaseButton" ref={this.hide} hidden={false} onClick={this.changeSize.bind(this)}>+</button>
        <span id="textSpan" ref={this.checkInput} onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>{this.props.text}</span>

       </div>
);
}
```

right now their hidden attribute is false so I can see them.Here's the html which is not much:

```
    <div id='container'></div>

    <script type="text/jsx">

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <FontChooser min='4' max='40' size='16' text='You can change me!' bold='false'/>
   </div>,
document.getElementById('container'))
;

    </script>
```

So far all I have managed is for the browser console(I'm using Firefox react component addon) to confirm there is a functioning event that doesn't really work, as in when I click the text, the buttons or the input checkbox the props does change to false or true every click but that's about it.

I appreciate it if someone could guide me through this.
**NOTE:**
just in case nothing is imported, also I setup a local server with Nodejs

Comment: I don't see style attribute or className's being set or changed based on state, which I think will point you in the right direction, in your render, have something like

`<span id="textSpan" ref={this.checkInput} onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)} style={{ fontWeight: this.state.bold ? ' 800' : '400' }}>{this.props.text}</span>`.

You shouldn't need to worry about refs for this by the way, unless there is a sideffect you are wanting

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice! I manage to hide and show on click so far

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example of what you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-cookies-v7w3l?file=/src/App.js

Basically, I have 4 variables: text, fontWeight, fontSize and showTools.
Each button has its own task and also you can select if show or not.

In React you don't have to care about ids like in older frameworks. You can generate the elements just in the place where you are with the information which you need. So, basically, we have the 4 variables and use them wisely where we want (as styles props, as text and  even as a conditional to show components). It's the magic of React and JSX.

In the code I've use hooks, part of the latest definition of React. For that my Components is functional and not a Class. it makes it easier  and faster for examples and prototyping.

The tools are show by default just to let you play with it

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");
  const [boldFont, setBoldFont] = React.useState(false);
  const [fontSize, setFontSize] = React.useState(14);
  const [showTools, setShowTools] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={{
          fontWeight: boldFont ? "bold" : "normal",
          fontSize: `${fontSize}px`
        }}
      >
        <span onClick={() => setShowTools(!showTools)}>
          {text || "Text Example"}
        </span>
      </div>
      {showTools && (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setBoldFont(!boldFont)}>Bold</button> |
          <button onClick={() => setFontSize(fontSize + 1)}>A+</button>
          <button onClick={() => setFontSize(fontSize - 1)}>a-</button>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={text}
            onChange={event => {
              setText(event.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```